# What is the effect of paging on jqgrid's getChangedCells method when using clientArray(clientside) for editing?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, pagination

I am using jqgrid with clientArray option for editing;My grid is using paging; Will the jqgrid getChangedCells method return the correct changed rows even after changing pages several times with a possibility of data from the server having changed?- for example if new rows are available from the server that will now appear in my grid if I page back;
Wont there be a rowId conflict - the new rowIds will be pointing to different rows from the ones before new data became available?
I guess I could always order my server data by the autoincrementing primary key?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found out today on experimenting; paging (server side) a jqgrid clears the result of getChangedCells; I had to create a utility function to store the getChangedCells array so that it persists across paging;
Im doing this so I can submit all the changes separately
In jqgrid options I have something like:

```
('#grid').jqgrid({
  ....
  cellEdit:true,
  cellSubmit:'clientArray',
  colModel: [ {...,editable:true,
                   dataInit:function(el){
                     el.autocomplete({...});
                   }...} ... ],
  afterSaveCell:function(){
                $.retainChangesOnPaging();
                 }
  ....
```

});

and in the utility retainChangesOnPaging I have something like:

```
(function(){
  var retainedChanges;
  retainedChanges = new Array();
  $.retainChangesOnPaging = function(){
    var changedCells = ('#grid').jqGrid('getChangedCells');
    // loop over changedCells array, removing duplicates if you want to...
      return  retainedChanges.push(/* this is inside the loop; push current value to array*/);
     ....
  }
   $.getRetainedChanges = function(){
     return retainedChanges;
   }
})(jQuery);
```

then when Im ready to submit all changes to server, I call $.getRetainedChanges
Another question : is the way I used the retainChangesOnPaging correct? something seems wrong though the code works - can I make it better in any way? are my closures ok?

Answer (score 0):

I think when you store if same row already exists then it will be better to override the existing row in the retainedChanges because user might override the exsisting row again and again.