# how to get data from jqgrid clientArray?

Tags: php, jqgrid

hi i'm trying to acces the data from my Grid but i can't get the data from clientArray i'm use this code i don't know how get the data for send to remote server before get data

```
 var dataGridNuevaCajaMatriz = [{
                '40': 0,
                '50': 0,
                '60': 0,
                '70': 0,
                '80': 0,
                '90': 0,
                '100': 0,
                '110': 0
            }];

            jQuery("#grid_nueva_caja_matriz").jqGrid({
            data: dataGridNuevaCajaMatriz,       
            datatype: "local",
            //datatype: "json",
            loadonce: true,         
            /*height:'400',*/
            colNames:['40','50','60','70','80','90', '100', '110'],
            colModel:[
            //{name:'seleccion',index:'', width:50, align: 'center',editable: false, formatoptions: {disabled : false}, editoptions: {value:"1:0" },editrules:{required:false}},
            {name:'40',index:'40', width:50, align:"center",editable:true},
            {name:'50',index:'50', width:50, align:"center",editable:true}, 
            {name:'60',index:'60', width:50, align:"center",editable:true}, 
            {name:'70',index:'70', width:50, align:"center",editable:true}, 
            {name:'80',index:'80', width:50, align:"center",editable:true}, 
            {name:'90',index:'90', width:50, align:"center",editable:true}, 
            {name:'100',index:'100', width:50, align:"center",editable:true},
            {name:'110',index:'110', width:50, align:"center",editable:true},   
            ],
            rowNum:999999,
            pager: '#pager_nueva_caja_matriz',
            toppager:false,
            pgbuttons:false,
            pginput:false,
            rowList:false,
            gridview:false, 
            shrinkToFit: false,
            jsonReader: {
            repeatitems : false,
            cellEdit: true,
            cellsubmit : 'clientArray',
            editurl: 'clientArray', 
            },      
            loadError: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            message_error('ERROR','HTTP message body (jqXHR.responseText): ' + '<br>' + jqXHR.responseText);
            },
            //ondblClickRow
            onSelectRow: function(){
                var row_id = $("#grid_nueva_caja_matriz").getGridParam('selrow');
                jQuery('#grid_nueva_caja_matriz').editRow(row_id, true);
            }
            });

            jQuery("#form_nueva_caja_matriz #grid_nueva_caja_matriz").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager_nueva_caja_matriz',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
```

how get the data clienteArray i can't get these. please help me
thanks

Comment: Which editing mode you want to use in the grid: cell editing or inline editing? You can't use both editing modes in the same grid. Currently you use `cellEdit: true, cellsubmit : 'clientArray'` for cell editing and you included start of `editRow` of row select (see `onSelectRow` callback). You use very strange column names (`name` property in `colModel`) and **no rowids** in input data (no `id` property for every for with unique value). You question is not clear too. Do you need to have some "Save" button on the page where you want to get the modified data for sending there to the server?

Answer (score 0):

The jqgrid manual says that if you're using it in the `"clientArray"` mode, you won't need that `editurl` parameter. http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing

This older post had some problems with the `clientArray` mode but seem to be somewhat solved: [What is the effect of paging on jqgrid's getChangedCells method when using clientArray(clientside) for editing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113640/what-is-the-effect-of-paging-on-jqgrids-getchangedcells-method-when-using-clien)